# How to make EXT JS model and proxy store work? (please_help!)

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1

I hav'nt understood how to link server data and form's field by using REST api.

I have form with some selectfields. And i have values for this particularly fields on server. I think that forms can get data from store trought model (y/n?). If it is true i have a question: how to add exist forms to model?
So main target - get values from server to the exist selectfields of exist form trought REST API.

Here is what I have now:
-proxy store:

```
Ext.define('Foresto.store.RESTstore',{ 
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
storeID:'reststore',
proxy: {
    type:'rest',
    url:'http://localhost:6666/api/form',
    reader:{
        type: 'json',
        root: ''
    }
},
autoLoad: true});
```

-one from forms:

```
Ext.define('Foresto.view.forms.Cutarea', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
title: 'ForestoL',
header: {
    cls: 'header-cls',

},
scrollable: true,
xtype: 'forestoL',

url: 'save-form.php',

items: [{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    label: 'Field1',
    name: 'name'
},{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    label: 'Field2',
    name: 'allotment'
}] ...
```

Please hepl!
Thanks,
Artur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2n0o) of a basic remote combobox.

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'My Combo',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'title',
    anchor: '100%',
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: ['id', 'title'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'records.json'
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: So creating of model is unnecessary ? I can just to integrate store for each field?

Comment: It depends on the use-case, if your stores share the same model then having it centralised would be better.